# CRC 16 bit (Polynomial 0x1021) CCITT calculation with initial value 0x0000

Tags: c#, crc16

Well I am scratching my head and very close to break it with hammer. I am trying to calculate CRC16 bit CCITT and it not giving me what its supposed to. I have searched almost everything and dont know what i am missing.

This is the full packet with last two bytes of CRC calculation

> 54 A1 4A 03 E7 03 D4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 CA

for now i am adding sync byte which is 0x54 if I dont add sync byte the packet would be

> 54 A1 4A 03 E7 03 D4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 65 CF

both CRC values (64 CA && 65 CF) are wrong. I supposed to get 72 DC && 99 3F respectively.

this is the code I am using to calculate CRC16 bit

```
private static ushort CRCCalc(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort wCRC = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            wCRC = (ushort)(wCRC ^ (data[i] << 8));

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((wCRC & 0x8000) != 0)
                    wCRC = (ushort)((wCRC << 1) ^ 0x1021);
                else
                    wCRC <<= 1;
            }
        }
        return wCRC;
    }
```

Any Comments...?

Thanks

Comment: The code works fine for me: http://rextester.com/SRPW93356

Comment: I am an idiot. I was not feeding the right values in the array. you are right @PeterK.

Thanks